# boolean example in Schildt book

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

I'm really new to Java, but it sucks all my free time, it's very interesting to study, but I need a little help.

Here's an example of Boolean test from Schildt's book:

```
public class BooleanTest {
public static void main(String args[]){
    boolean b;
    b = false;
    System.out.println("Expression b " +b);
    b = true;
    System.out.println("Expression b " + b);
    if (b) System.out.println("This code is ok.");
    b = false;
    if (b) System.out.println("This code is not ok.");
    System.out.println("10 > 9 " + (10>9));
}}
```

This code shows me result:

> Expression b false
>
> Expression b true
>
> This code is ok.
>
> 10 > 9 true

First line is ok, second is ok, third too, but why the fourth doesn't show me "The code is not ok.", 'cause there is "b=false" and it should say that? Why it jumps to the last System.out.println?

Can someone add commentaries to this example? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If b is true, print "This code is not ok", it's false so it doesn't print it.

Comment: Hmm... does 'if (b) blah blah blah' means 'if (b==true) blah blah blah' ? And that's why If statement skipped 'cause I said that b=false before?

Comment: @Artemis yeap...I got it. That was quite silly from my side. Thanks a lot for Your answer and help!

Comment: Yes if(b) is short notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this line :

```
b = false;
if (b) System.out.println("This code is not ok.");
```

b is false. So the if statement is false and the instruction in the if block is not executed, no matter the content of the String !

Answer (score 2):

Basically you don't use `else` and your `if` condition applies only to the next instruction after the `if` statement, if you don't use parenthesis.

```
if (b) System.out.println("This code is not ok.");
System.out.println("10 > 9 " + (10>9));
```

Goes like this (assuming b == true)

1. `if(b)  //true`
2. `System.out.println("This code is ok."); //This code is ok`
3. `b = false // b == false`
4. `if (b) //false`
5. `System.out.println("10 > 9 " + (10>9)); //10 > 9 true`

To have what you thought it was, your code should have been:

```
    public class BooleanTest {
public static void main(String args[]){
    boolean b;
    b = false;
    System.out.println("Expression b " +b);
    b = true;
    System.out.println("Expression b " + b);
    if (b) System.out.println("This code is ok.");
    else b = false;
    if (b) System.out.println("This code is not ok.");
    System.out.println("10 > 9 " + (10>9));
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (b) System.out.println("b was true");
```

that line says: only if `b` is true do what comes after the closing `)`. Since `b` is false, the rest of the line is not executed. More verbose example:

```
if (b) {
    System.out.println("b was true");
} else {
    System.out.println("b was false");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (b)` equal to `if(b!=false)`

and as you see the third placement is  `b=true`

fourth placement is `b=false` but the condition is the same `if (b)` = `if(b!=false)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple routine which should give you the concrete knowledge

```
if (true) { 
   //do true
}

if (false) {
   // not true, never go here
}
```

Using curly brackets to ensure multiple lines get included in the block else only 1 line directly after the "if" is executed.